# PHP connection with SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

SQL server connection shows error when using mssql_connect() or sqlsrv_connect() .Call to undefined function mssql_connect() or Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() error is displaying. In my server IIS and wamp server is running. can any one please help...

Comment: <?php
   
 $server  = "localhost";
 $user   = "Administrator";
 $pass   = "";
 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"$user", "PWD"=>"$pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} 


?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the php.ini file remove the semicolon  before the extention
it will probably be in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` 
enable your extention by removing the semicolon
change this with

```
 ;extension=php_mssql.dll
```

with

```
 extension=php_mssql.dll
```

and restart your xampp

Comment: Iam running PHP in IIS server. I have also tried with WAMP server, but it shows the same error

Answer (score 1):

"The MSSQL extension is enabled by adding extension=php_mssql.dll to php.ini."

For more information : [MSSQL Installing/Configuring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php)